How to make new variable in SPSS based on values from three other variables
In SPSS I need to make a new variable that are weights for survey results. I have the weights calculated, and they need to be added all depending on the values of the other three varaibles. So for example: age = 1 AND location = 1 AND gender = 1, the new variable (let's call it "weight") should get the value 0.8.
I tried this command in SPSS, but its not working:
IF (gender = 1 & age = 1 & location = 1) weight = 0.8.
EXECUTE.

All the three variables in SPSS are set as numeric, and weight is set as numeric. Does anyone know how I can resolve this?

I don't see a reason why this shouldn't worm. Can you describe what DID happen? did you get an error message? were wrong values assigned? did nothing happen? In any case, assigning all the weights can get tedious - consider creating a table of weights and using match files to get all the weights in the table assigned automatically.

"Using & instead of AND in SPSS can indeed cause problems. In SPSS, the correct logical operator for "AND" is AND, while & is used for bitwise operations on numeric expressions, which is not appropriate for logical conditions" - ChatGPT
